# Dynamically removing/adding controls on a Windows Forms form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to remove and add a control at runtime on a Windows Forms form. The problem is, that the control must have the exact same size, location and anchors as another one.

If the user opens the window and a certain criteria is fulfilled, I want to delete the old control and replace it by another.

So, I tried this:

```
RichTextBox InsideText = new RichTextBox();
InsideText.Location = InsideBox.Location;
InsideText.Size = InsideBox.Size;

Controls.Remove(InsideBox);
Controls.Add(InsideText);
```

But, as expected, it didn't work. The `InsideBox` is not removed and the `InsideText` not added.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Did you check that the Visible property of InsideText is true?

Comment: This is basically how I do this, and it works for me. When you remove a control from the parent control's collection it will go away. Are you sure you're removing it from the correct collection?

Comment: I don't think I've ever had this problem with dynamic creation/removal of controls. Have you ensured that Visible is true? Have you tried setting the X and Y, Width and Height, instead of using Size and Location (I always use X, Y, Width, Height, old habit I think), that's the only difference I can think of between when I do it and this example. Might help if there's any other relevant code we can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest that the easier way would be to:

1. Add a panel in the correct location with the correct anchor, etc. set.
2. Add control1 inside that panel set to full `Dock`
3. Just remove control1 and add control2 inside that panel instead and set it to Dock.

Then all the size stuff, etc. is done by the one Panel instead of having to copy that around.